# Passing a value to end message of game

Tags: python, parameters, parameter-passing

I have this hang man code but i want to add parameter passing to it

```
import time

import random


#Procedure
def Username():
    name = raw_input("What is your name?")
    print "Hello, "+ name, "Time to play hangman!"
    print "\n"

def loading():
    #Makes the user wait for 1 second
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Start guessing..."
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return

def randwords():
    global words
    words = ["keyboard", "motherboard", "python", "powersupply"]
    words = random.choice(words)

#Main Program
Username()

loading()


randwords()

guesses =""

turns = 12


#while loop


while turns > 0:

    failed = 0

    for char in words:

        if char in guesses: 

            print char,

        else:

            print"_",

            failed += 1    

    if failed == 0:
        print "\nyou won Well Done"


        break
    print


    guess = raw_input("guess a character:")


    guesses += guess

    if guess not in words:


        turns -= 1


        print "wrong\n"


        print "you have", + turns, "more guesses"

        if turns == 0:

            print "you lose GAME OVER\n"


input()
Username()
waiting()

Random
```

I want it to take the name value, user types in at the start and then pass that value into the end messages.

Example

```
print "you have won (NAME) Well Done"
```

or

```
print "you lose (NAME) GAME OVER"
```

Please help me somebody because I can solve the problem every time I try I get a error message.

Comment: what did you try and what error message did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare 'name' as global variable.

```
name = '' # before def Username
```

And before you assign a value to this variable, do following:

```
global name
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
```

You may then use this variable anywhere in the script to print its value.

```
print name, "you lose GAME OVER\n"
```

P.S : To write to a gllobal variable, you must precede with:

```
global <variable-name>
```

whereas, you may read its value in normal way

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the name from the function 'Username()'.

```
def Username():
    ...
    return name

def main():
    ...
    name = Username()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks this worked and helped me a lot, so thank you for your help